# Character limit in webservice at wsdl level

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere

I hace deployed a java WebService in an application using WebSphere AST. I need to limit the length of some fields (Strings) and I wondered if I can do that at the wsdl instead of coding some validations at java level.

I mean, if rigth now I have the elements defined like this:

```
<element name="code" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Can I set some property that restrict the max length of "code"?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<element name="code" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="2"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```